# How to remove forward slashes from a vector in R?

Tags: r, regex, string, substring, stringr

I have a large character vector in R that looks, in part, like this:

```
VRMMs = c("201905031740 METAR KDCA 031740Z AUTO ///11KT 10SM SCT041 24/18 A3000 RMK T02400180 MADISHF")
```

I need to remove those three consecutive forward slashes from every observation. They're not always in the same place or in the same context. I've tried doing it with `stringr`, but no luck:

```
library(stringr)
VRMMs <- str_replace(VRMMs, "///", "")
```

Comment: Are you sure the attempt with `str_replace()` didn't work?  Based on the example there's no reason it shouldn't.

Comment: If you want a shorthand, `str_remove` is the same as calling `str_replace` with `""` as the replacement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `sub`

```
sub("///", "", VRMMs)

#[1] "201905031740 METAR KDCA 031740Z AUTO 11KT 10SM SCT041 24/18 A3000 RMK T02400180 MADISHF"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can place it inside square bracket

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(VRMMs, "[/]{3,}", "")
#[1] "201905031740 METAR KDCA 031740Z AUTO 11KT 10SM SCT041 24/18 A3000 RMK T02400180 MADISHF"
```

Also, the OP's use of `///` is working fine with `str_replace`

```
str_replace(VRMMs, "///", "")
#[1] "201905031740 METAR KDCA 031740Z AUTO 11KT 10SM SCT041 24/18 A3000 RMK T02400180 MADISHF"
```

NOTE: Here, the OP used `str_replace` and the question is about `str_replace`

---

If there are more than one instance, we can use `gsub` in `base R`

```
gsub("[/]{3,}", "", VRMMs)
```